# Skip saving row if slug already exists to avoid IntegrityError - Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, slugify

I'm setting up a function in my Django Views that calls an API and save the data into my Postgresql database.

Everthing was working fine until I got an `IntegrityError slugkey already exists`, so I'm trying to find a way to skip or ignore the row if the `slugify slug` already exists.

Here's my Django Models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2047, default='')
    link = models.TextField(max_length=500, default='')

    ptags = TaggableManager()

    image = models.ImageField(max_length=500, default='images/zero-image-found.png')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def _ptags(self):
        return [t.name for t in self.ptags.all()]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('experience',
                       kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.destination
```

And this is my function in Views:

```
def api_data(request):
    if request.GET.get('mybtn'):  # to improve, == 'something':
        resp_1 = requests.get(
            "https://www.headout.com/api/public/v1/product/listing/list-by/city?language=fr&cityCode=ROME&limit=5000&currencyCode=CAD",
            headers={
                "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
            })
        resp_1_data = resp_1.json()
        base_url_2 = "https://www.headout.com/api/public/v1/product/get/"


        for item in resp_1_data['items']:
            print('parsing, translating and saving item {}'.format(item['id']))
            # concat ID to the URL string
            url = '{}{}'.format(base_url_2, item['id'] + '?language=fr')

            # make the HTTP request
            resp_2 = requests.get(
                url,
                headers={
                    "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
                })
            resp_2_data = resp_2.json()

            try:
                descriptiontxt = resp_2_data['contentListHtml'][0]['html'][0:2040] + ' ...'
            except (IndexError, KeyError) as e:
                continue

            #Parsing the description to get only the text in <p>
            soup = BeautifulSoup(descriptiontxt, 'lxml')

            try:
                parsed = soup.find('p').text
            except AttributeError:
                continue

            if len(parsed) == 0:
                continue

            #Translation
            translation = Translator().translate(text=parsed, dest='fr').text

            titlename = item['name']
            titlefr = Translator().translate(text=titlename, dest='fr').text

            destinationname = item['city']['name']
            destinationfr = Translator().translate(text=destinationname, dest='fr').text


            Product.objects.get_or_create(
                title=titlefr,
                destination=destinationfr,
                description=translation,
                link=item['canonicalUrl'],
                image=item['image']['url'],
            )

            time.sleep(2)

    return render(request, "form.html")
```

How can I fix this?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I've tacked on a number suffix in this case. Code below to do that which I'm sure came from s/o some time ago. Place in your Product model.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # create a unique slug for this record
    suffix = 0
    potential = base = slugify(f'{self.title[:50]}')
    self.slug = None
    while not self.slug:
        if suffix:
            potential = f'{base}-{suffix}'
        if not Product.objects.filter(slug=potential).exists():
            self.slug = potential
        suffix += 1

    super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```